# При получении графического контекста из JPanel получаю null Почему?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Вот код: Ну и вопрос: почему ссылка на Graphics нулевая?

```
package CardGame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                  createAndShowGUI();
              }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        Tr.db("Created GUI on EDT?"SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()); 
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing PaintDemo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p.setOpaque(true);
        p.setBackground(Color.red);
        Graphics g = p.getGraphics();
        //вот здесь вылетает исключение нул пойнт ексепшн
        //при попытке на панели что нить написать
        g.drawString("hello", 10, 50);
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, видимо потому, что `p.getGraphics()` возвращает null.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде `p.getGraphics()` возвращает `null`. Всё дело в том, что `f.setVisible(true)` идёт после него. Пока ничего нет, `getGraphics()` будет возвращать `null`. Должно быть как-то так

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing PaintDemo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    p.setOpaque(true);
    p.setBackground(Color.red);
    f.add(p);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.pack();
    Graphics g = p.getGraphics();
    g.drawString("hello", 10, 50);
}
```